# Unset http_proxy environment variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, proxy

> **Updated 11/03**: After doing some test with your suggestions, I only can
>   be sure about one thing: there is something related to the graphical
>   environment, because if I login through `ssh` or using a virtual
>   terminal, the variable is not defined. Any new idea?

I have defined in some persistent way the http_proxy variable. Always I open a terminal, I have the http_proxy already defined.

This is not my desired behaviour, so I'm looking where I defined the http_proxy environment variable.

I'm pretty sure that is something user related, because with other users in the same computer I don't have the problem.

I have checked the `.bashrc` and other bash-related configuration files, but none of them include the http_proxy variable definition.

Obviously, I can `unset` the variable without any problem, but I want to know where the hell is the variable defined.

Comment: Have you looked under `/etc/profile.d/`?

Comment: @jasonwryan I just looked under it, and no `http_proxy` definition is there

Comment: Which desktop environment do you use? If you've set up a proxy in your desktop environment, it might set this variable as well.

Comment: @Gilles I'm using Gnome 3, in Debian Unstable. I have checked in the network configuration dialogs and the proxy is not configured. Maybe a value in gsettings/dconf can assign a environment variable?

Comment: Mmmm nice idea, @Gilles. I tried to print the `http_proxy` value in VT1 (Control+Alt+F1) and the environment variable is not defined!

Comment: I don't know if there's a generic mechanism to set an environment variable, but I think Gnome does set `http_proxy` if you set the proxy. It's weird that the proxy isn't configured in the network configuration dialog, however. Try grepping for the value (e.g. `find ~ -type f -exec grep -F proxy.example.com {} +`).

Comment: I have tried already, looking in both `/etc` and `$HOME`. I have checked the gsettings proxy configuration values are these are unset

Comment: Hi! Finally I just figured what the problem is: when the change from gconf to dconf happened on Debian's Gnome version, I had the `http_proxy` configured. I don't have the proxy configued into my Gnome configuration (now, under dconf system), but I had it under gconf. One of scripts run when the user session is opened is a program to import gconf properties to the session. So, the proxy is not shown in my Gnome configuration but it is applied to the environment variables. I remove the values from gconf system and I forget about the problem. Thanks for point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Yuo could try a grep in your home directory or in *etc*. Something like:

```
 $ cd ~ 
~$ grep -Ri http_proxy *
```

Comment: Please no signatures on posts.

Comment: I tried something very similar: `find $HOME -type f | xargs grep -i http_proxy`, and it doesn't return anything

Comment: @JoseLSegura Do the same thing with `/etc` in addition to `$HOME`.

Comment: @Gilles I have tried with both `$HOME` and `/etc`, and looking for `http_proxy` (with `-i` grep option, to ignore case) and for the defined value for the variable. Returns nothing in the 4 scenarios. This is the reason because I'm here asking this :-D Estrange thing...

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables are saved in `/etc/environment`

```
cat /etc/environment | grep "http_proxy"
```

And proxy for aptitude are save in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf | grep "http::proxy"
```

Comment: The `http_proxy` is defined for all the environment, not only for APT (for example, with wget it tried to use the defined proxy). My `/etc/environment` file is empty. Nice try

Comment: How you defined the http_proxy?

Comment: I don't remember, that's the problem :-D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this question already has an answer, but this is my `/etc/environment`:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
http_proxy="http://192.168.0.1:8080"
ftp_proxy="ftp://192.168.0.1:8080"
https_proxy="https://192.168.0.1:8080"
export http_proxy ftp_proxy https_proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem (after using Fiddler proxy to debug some stuff - I guess that was the source of problems).

Clearing out gconf dir:

```
rm ~/gconf/system/proxy -R
rm ~/gconf/system/http_proxy -R
```

And **relogging** did the trick.